# Some GUI elements missing on MacBook Pro 2015 mid 15"

Tags: graphics

I've installed Elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya on MacBook Pro2015 mid 15" with rEFInd used.

When I get into touchpad setting, some GUI elements are missing:

[image]

In **Touchpad** section, there's nothing.

**HOWEVER** if I move a mounse pointer around that empty space, GUI elements that were invisible appears:

[image]

My system configuraion is:

> MacBook Pro 2015 mid 15"
>   Iris 5200 Pro graphic, no external graphic
>   Elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya 64-bit
>   Based on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Kernel: 3.19.0-26)

And I have `grub` set:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off nomodeset"
```

Loaded modules are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/caba4a2ff9f67f8c764f

Does anyone have a such issue and have fixed it?

Comment: I think it is because of the nomodeset option. I'm not sure how hard it is to install the correct graphics driver on a MBP?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue on my MacBook Pro 15" Late 2012 (rMBP 10,1). The Bluetooth dropdown panel in the menu bar seems to also be affected by this. I can reproduce this issue both by using the integrated Intel GPU as well as by using the dedicated Nvidia GPU with nouveau, therefore I think it might not be a driver issue. I am not using rEFInd, but booting via Grub2 directly. The parameters only include the `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'` option, no `nomodeset` or anything else. Booting without it doesn't affect the problem. I hope this helps in pinpointing the issue. EDIT: I just noticed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to the elementary dark theme solved the issue for me, see [UI elements are not displayed](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/ui-elements-are-not-displayed)