# How can I install elementary tweaks on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, thirdpartyapps

How can I install elementary tweaks on elementary OS 0.4 Loki Beta?

Answer (score 20):

You can install [redesigned](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) version elementary tweaks on Loki.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common --no-install-recommends
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

[image]

*Note: please, read [elementary team's stance](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/38z164/what_is_the_elementary_teams_stance_on_elementary/crz5dsf/) before installation tweaks.*

Comment: I got 2 errors :
* it's not signed thus no updates
* "Unable to locate package elementary-tweaks"

Comment: These commands arent workimg for me. I got the latest release of Loki tho I dont know which version exactly that is.

Comment: Those should work...

The && will simply run the next command, so if you were pasting them into terminal line by line, that may have been the problem. If you type the above in command-by-command without the &&, you should get it.

Comment: I did them with apt-get first. I thought this was the mistake so i did them with only apt now. Still cant find tweaks. Do i need to reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any ppa. I manually downloaded the "elementary tweaks" packages from https://launchpad.net/~philip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks and I installed them with Eddy  https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy.desktop

Comment: you won't get updates that way though will you

Comment: The last update was October 10, 2017. If I see new updates useful I'll replace it manually